# testing recurring contributions -- gone wrong!

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

Please help!

I've made a new recurring contribution page for membership renewals. I tested to contribution page to make sure recurring contributions would go through -- they went through so I *thought* it was all good to go.

I tested the page the following week just to make sure it was still running smoothly and... nothing. Now, anytime I submit one-time member dues (i.e. a one-time contribution of $30) it works fine, but once I add that I want to contribute that amount of money every month, on the user side it says the payment went though Authorize for processing, but it doesn't show up in Authorize and it doesn't record anything in Civi.

Curiously, after I complete a transaction, I "told a friend" and then that action showed up in my activities in Civi. That is to say, something is connecting, but recurring transactions are just not.

I've submitted them under my name and another's. Both unsuccessful.

Payment processor: Authorize.net
Civi version: 5.17.5
Drupal core version: 8.7.8

Answer (score 2):

The recurring contribution workflow is more complicated than the one-time workflow. For authorize.net, it means that a request for a recurring contribution is sent, but relies on the payment processor to come back with any information about whether the recurring contribution has completed or not (as well as communicating about any future transactions), and typically that will not happen immediately, but at some later time.

I'd guess that you will see pending payments in CiviCRM for these recurring requests, and that for some reason your payment processor account is not configured to properly handle recurring requests (i.e. the callback or IPN isn't firing properly). Perhaps your payment processor account is used for other purposes than online payments?

Comment: Well, we have one contribution page configured so that recurring payments are listed as contribution amounts (this page processes recurring contributions successfully). I want to set up recurring contributions as a membership setting/price set in a contrib pg - I did it once and the recurring contributions went through fine. But now - a week later - when I submit a recurring contrib from the user's side, the contrib page set up with a membership price set wont register a recurring contrib, wont even send it to Authorize and doesn't show up (even as pending) in civi. (thanks for you answer btw)

Comment: Ah, so that sounds like a CiviCRM core configuration or code issue, i.e. your configuration seems to have convinced CiviCRM that it doesn't need to talk to Authorize.net. Perhaps you're not even being asked for credit card credentials? If it "used to work and now doesn't" I suspect there are additional complications going on.